Name of older science fiction movie
Black and White movie or short or episode. Only saw it on TV once approx 30 years ago.
Alien Creature invades a space craft by transferring from another ship as a rapid wisp. It occupies one room on the ship, and appears as a large evil stationary version of a "minion," i.e. a one eyed dome shaped creature with mouth big enough to encompass a person. It uses hypnotism or telepathy to change its appearance and lure people into its mouth. People that fall for the lure enter the mouth. They soon are expelled from the mouth as a skeleton striped of all flesh.
The hero manages to circumvent the illusions of safety, and escape the lure of the creature long enough to stab it in the eye, killing and deflating it.
Anyone remember that one?  I've searched for this many different ways and come up blank.

Not black-and-white, but I think you're describing the Space: 1999 episode Dragon's Domain, (1975).

On arriving at Ultra, they marveled at its similarity to Earth and
  preparations were made for a manned landing. While orbiting behind
  Ultra—out of direct communication with Alpha mission control—the ship
  encountered a collection of alien spacecraft. No life signs were
  detected from any of the derelicts. By consensus, the crew decided to
  dock with one of the silent vessels.
As the airlock opened, there was an unexpected phenomenon—swirling
  light, raging wind, screeching noise—and King shouted to Cellini to
  close the airlock. Emitting a deafening electronic scream, a huge,
  vaguely octopus-like creature with prehensile tentacles, one blazing
  eye and a fiery maw materialised, filling the aft portion of the main
  module. When King attempted to seal it off with the emergency
  bulkheads, its incredibly strong appendages prevented the closure of
  the doors—which shorted out the ship's auto-systems. The crew's
  efforts to defend themselves came to naught. One by one, they were
  hypnotised into inaction by the creature, devoured alive, and their
  smoking remains regurgitated.

The episode is on Youtube.  The creature appears here.

The episode referenced in above answer is very similar, and perhaps it directly drew from the one I am still trying to locate. The one I am still looking for was likely made before Space:1999, and was in B&W. The creature in the one I'm thinking of did not have long reaching tentacles, the skeletons that were regurgitated were clean skeletons, and when killed, the alien appeared much different than this one.
Thanks for posting this answer as I had not seen that episode of Space: 1999 before, and maybe it will set me on the right path.

Interesting, when I read the question I also really thought the Cosmos 1999 episode was a perfect match... I hope someone finds the answer, I'm curious to learn about the "original" !
